# Rename File Based From Its Content

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm hoping someone can help me out with a command or batch file?

I have alot of files with some meta information inside them.

I'm trying to read a specific lines and rename the file from some of its content.

This is an example of the content,

```
<recording>
    <file name="currentfilename.wav">
        <fixedtags>
            <tenant value="default" />
            <campaignname value="1864" />
            <agentid value="600+1+488295" />
            <sessionid value="" />
            <telephonenumber value="99999" />
            <diallednumber value="" />
            <agentrecordedoutcome value="0" />
            <telephonyoutcome value="10" />
            <committment value="0" />
            <successrating value="0" />
            <callstarttime value="43174.629577" />
            <calllength value="16762" />
            <date value="2018-03-15" />
            <sessionGUID value="" />
            <EndpointGuid value="" />
            <SessionUniqueId value="" />
            <Direction value="Outbound" />
        </fixedtags>
        <customtags>
            <tagone value="" />
            <tagtwo value="" />
            <tagthree value="" />
            <tagfour value="" />
            <tagfive value="" />
            <tagsix value="" />
        </customtags>
        <hash></hash>
    </file>
</recording>
```

This is the output in trying to put together

Example, each name in the file is from the content within the file.

```
campaignname-telephonenumber-date-callstarttime-agentid-Direction.txt
```

so the output would look something like this

```
1864-99999-20180315-43174.629577-600+1+488295-Outbound.txt
```

Thanks,
Stewart

Comment: You should use XML-specific tools such as xmlstarlet or xpath

Comment: What environment are you working in? the [tag:batch-file] tag refers to Windows batch language (`CMD.EXE`), which is different from [tag:bash], which refers to a UNIX/Linux shell, whose language is very different.

Comment: Windows batch files do not have a native method of reading and writing XML files.  You can only brute force reading the xml and if the XML format changes the brute force code would most likely need to be changed.  If you are using Windows, your other scripting choices are Powershell, Vbscript and Jscript which all have native capability to read and write XML.

Comment: On bash, assuming each tag is unique, you can combine `grep` and `cut` do to this (among other possibilities).  But we are shooting in the dark until we know what platform you are working on.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I don't mind using windows or linux

Comment: @Nic3500 the main layout is always the same, only the value="input" is changed

Comment: @StewartJones - Are you saying that you have both options? The files are stored on a network share that is accessible from both a Windows system and a Linux system?

Comment: @Squashman - FWIW, PowerShell is now available for Linux (and MacOS), not just Windows.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Ya, because Linux guys want to use Windows tools!  ;-
)

Comment: @Nic3500 - You'd actually be surprised how many Linucians have been impressed with PowerShell when I've showed it to them...

Comment: I do not doubt it, I have used it.  It's just from a unix guy's point of view, there is always a bias against Borg technology (you will be assimilated).

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a [request for assistance with a minimal version of your own code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This makes your question [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49324504/edit) and I'll happily retract my close vote.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use XSLT, assuming your files are regular.  The following will take your XML and return the filename...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:template match="/recording/file/fixedtags">
<xsl:value-of select="campaignname/@value"/>-<xsl:value-of select="telephonenumber/@value"/>-<xsl:value-of select="date/@value"/>-<xsl:value-of select="callstarttime/@value"/>-<xsl:value-of select="agentid/@value"/>-<xsl:value-of select="Direction/@value"/>.txt
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are in Bash, then xsltproc.  If using PowerShell, you have the native .NET 
libraries or even call an executable.  You may still need to sanitize the name just in case the XML contains stuff that's not filename friendly!  Probably a quick wrapper function makes all this easily reusable.

From there, loop through your files and do the rename.

Answer (score 0):

XML purists will not like this script, but it is simple and took me all of 5 minutes to do.

For OP, once you are satisfied it does what you want, remove the `echo " "` on the next to last line so the command is executed instead of just printed out.

The `/bin/ls *.xml` command can also be adjusted to process only the desired files, or if they are in another directory.

Assumption: tags are not repeated inside a unique XML file, and the format does not change (`<tag> value="SOMEVALUE" \>`)

The script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
for FILE in $(/bin/ls *.xml)
do
    campaingname=$(grep campaignname $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)
    telephonenumber=$(grep telephonenumber $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)
    thedate=$(grep "date" $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)
    callstarttime=$(grep callstarttime $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)
    agentid=$(grep agentid $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)
    Direction=$(grep Direction $FILE | cut -d'"' -f2)

    echo "mv $FILE $campaingname-$telephonenumber-$thedate-$callstarttime-$agentid-$Direction.txt"
done
```